# How to remove black border from <select> menu?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to remove black border from HTML select

[image]

Any suggestions for a simple solution?

Comment: Please add some code so we can help you...

Comment: I do not need change my select with <ul> <li>

Comment: @ErekleChumburidze plz add some html code in questions so we are help easily.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove select border then try below css

```
select {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}
```